# Two divs alignment for apple device

Tags: html, css, ios

I am trying to align two divs in the same row where one div has an image and another one is normal text
But the issue here is the first div is taking 100%(of image width) only in apple devices and in chrome and other browsers it is aligned correctly

Both above images are of apple device

Here is in chrome both divs are side by side and first div is not taking full width this is the correct scenario

```html
 <div class="d-flex align-items-center my-2">
      <div class="mr-2">
        <span *ngIf="companyData$ | async as companyData">
                    <sc-site-logo-image
                      *ngIf="site.display_image.indexOf('/images/site.png') !== -1"
                      [displayImage]="companyData.company_logo_uri"
                    >
                    </sc-site-logo-image>
                  </span>
        <div class="site-logo-thumbnail" *ngIf="image !== 'data:'">
          <img alt="" [src]="image" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="font-weight-bolder"> {{ site.display_name }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```js
  .site-logo-thumbnail {
    max-height: 48px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 48px;
    img {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  }
```

Here i cannot remove the width 100% of img tag.

I tried to fix this by adding width 100% to second div which is text but it dint work and i remove the width 100 from img tag then image size will create issue

Comment: What are all those spaces in the CSS properties doing? I imagine they have been put in only when you put the code into your question but please edit to accurately reflect the code you are actually using. And what prepricessir are you using, please tag it.

Comment: @AHaworth updated the css code

Comment: @AHaworth its for ios, found the issue on safari browser

Comment: What preprocessor are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth Do you mean C,C++?

Comment: I see that you have used styling that isn't .pure CSS for example. Are you using Angular or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245943/discussion-between-vinuta-and-a-haworth).

Answer (score 0):

why do you have a different class definition name in the CSS compared to the one definedon the HTML side on the DIV?

CSS side: .site - logo - thumbnail (it contains spaces)

HTML side: class="site-logo-thumbnail" (no spaces)

Comment: This should be a comment as it  is not framed as an answer.

Comment: i have updated the CSS code

Comment: Are the element properties set right?
I think you should set elements as "inline-block" and then specify height and width.
Please see here:
https://www.samanthaming.com/pictorials/css-inline-vs-inlineblock-vs-block/

Comment: elements properties are correct
already d-flex is added tp parent div

Comment: after adding display inline-block is not woking correctly

Comment: Is the margin property set to "auto"? What are your Left and Right margins?